# External website doesn't login ondemand through iframes?

Tags: apex, community, rest, iframe, developer

```
public class CreateEvent{
public Test__c login;           
    public CreateEvent(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){       
        this.login= (Test__c)controller.getRecord();             
    }
    public CreateEvent(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

    public Pagereference processCheck(){

       PageReference pageref = new PageReference('https://xxxxxxxx.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=xxxxxxx.com&password=xxxxxxx);       
       return pageref;                                 
  }   
}
```

once I click the button in visualforce  I get the response like below

```
<results>
<status code="ok"/>
  <OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN>
    <token>
          442adc814ed114ac272552be35684e1253444f5d7d5e05b2ee73d72adf287320
   </token>
  </OWASP_CSRF_TOKEN>
</results>
```

after that in same browser i opened another new tab and open the instance "https://xxxxxxxx.adobeconnect.com"
it directly open the home page of my instance without taking any login details.

---

but in realtime we don't show the response like above shown by clicking the button from visualforce page.

For that I have developed REST API.I get the above response in debug logs and redirected to the 
instance page but it doesn't taken login action ondemand.It just opens login page how can i resolve this

### this is my apex class

```
public class CreateEvent{
public Test__c login;           
    public CreateEvent(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){       
        this.login= (Test__c)controller.getRecord();             
    }
    public CreateEvent(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

    public Pagereference processCheck(){

       CreateWebinar.postfieldsFuture(username,password,url,cookie);
       PageReference pageref2 = new PageReference('/apex/AdobeIframe');
       return pageref;                                 
  }   
}
```

REST API

---

```
 global class CreateWebinar{  

    @future (callout=true)
    global static void postfieldsFuture(String username, String password,String url,String cookie){

        getParticipants(username, password, url,cookie);
    }

    global static HttpResponse getParticipants(String username, String password,String url,String cookie){  

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req =  new HttpRequest();          
        HttpResponse res =  new HttpResponse();          
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
        EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);              
        req.setEndpoint(url+'/api/xml?action=login&login='+username+'&password='+password+'&domain=acme.adobe.com&session='+cookie); 
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json'); 
        res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('MyResult == :'+res.getBody());        

        }
    }
```

### Redirect VF page : AdobeIframe

```
<apex:page>    
     <apex:iframe height="800" width="1230" src="https://xxxxxx.adobeconnect.com" scrolling="true"/> 
</apex:page>
```

how can I login ondemand to my instance

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description there is almost certainly a session cookie involved in the authentication process.

When you make the direct request with the browser the resulting cookie will be kept for subsequent requests.

However, when you make the direct HTTP call from Apex the resulting cookie will be ignored.

Check the `HttpResponse.getHeaderKeys()` for the cookie that comes back.

Now you have the cookie you will need to make all subsequent requests from Apex as well as you won't be able to set a browser cookie in the *.adobeconnect.com domain from Salesforce.